# My gmail password hacked in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, browser, passwords, gmail, internet-security

While writing a message using Firefox suddenly my gmail login details, including password, were pasted into the body of my message at the current cursor position and in the browser's find field (whole password and a bit of email address in the latter). I don't store my passwords in the browser nor in any of it's addons, although I keep it in one of Chrome's extensions. I don't use whole email address to login, only the user name, so it's very strange and worrying.

I must admit I clicked some suspicious link the same day (by checking the root of the domain first), but I quickly closed that page and after that I haven't used that password.

Both Avira and Spybot didn't detect anything.

What was it and what can I do to make sure my browser is safe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just realised it was ***KeePass*** (password manager) running in the background!

It has a global auto-type function, triggered by global hot-keys. So you may be filling a form on-line and accidently use that key combination. KeePass will then **automatically fill the form and submit!**

**I don't think it's safe**, so I recommend disabling it or using highly unlikely key combination.

To change it go to (within KeePass):

*Tools / Options / Integration tab / System wide hot-keys section / Global auto-type*

Answer (score 1):

You can Install and Use the extension called LastPass.

Visit lastpass.com

Comment: Thanks @Rishabh. I'm using KeePass, although your one offers some extra functionality. Gmail password is the only one I try not to store anywhere. In the case I described it seems that it was somehow captured and stored in RAM.

Comment: You can also mark this as an accepted answer; or edit it to add something you want and then mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: Thanks again @myselfpoddar, but I've just realised that it was KeePass